# Struct returned from method fails to satisfy interface despite the struct satisfying the interface when accessed directly

Tags: go

I am trying to create a container with getters that will return dependencies for my application.

I would like consumers of those dependencies to specify which dependencies from the container they use.

I am using this approach to make it easier for testing and to avoid having an excessive number of parameters on my functions.

pseduo code:

```golang
// Container with all the dependencies
type app struct {
  GetNewsFeed() *NewsFeed
  GetOtherDep() *OtherDep
}

// Consumer defines its dependencies
type IFooDependencies interface {
  GetNewsFeed() INewsFeed
}

func foo(app IFooDependencies) {}
```

Real world example / implementation of this approach:

```golang
// Interface of dependency
type INewsFeed interface {
    Add(item ...string)
}

// Implementation of dependency
type NewsFeed struct{}
func (*NewsFeed) Add(item ...string) {}
```

```golang
// Interface for container of dependencies
type IApp interface {
    GetNewsFeed() INewsFeed
}

// Implementation for container of things
type App struct {
    newsFeed *NewsFeed
}

func (a *App) GetNewsFeed() *NewsFeed {
    return a.newsFeed
}
```

```golang
// Putting it all together
func main() {
    var feed = &NewsFeed{}
    var iFeed INewsFeed = feed // This passes, so Newsfeed satisfies INewfeed
    var app = &App{feed}
    var iApp IApp = app // fails with:
    // *App does not implement IApp (wrong type for GetNewsFeed method)

    fmt.Println(feed, iFeed, app, iApp)
}
```

So `App.GetNewsFeed` returns an `*Newsfeed` where `IApp.GetNewsFeed` returns the interface `INewsfeed`.

When `*Newsfeed` is assigned to a variable containing `INewsfeed`, Go successfully compiles indicating that `Newfeed` correctly satisfies the interface.

However when a struct returns `*Newsfeed` from a method and that struct is assigned to a variable with an interface that looks like it should be satisfied (In this case assigning `App` to `IApp`, where on the `GetNewsFeed` method `INewsfeed` is returned on the interface rather than `*Newsfeed`), Go does not compile.

Why is that?

[Playground Link](https://go.dev/play/p/mf-K5HzzntD)

*EDIT*

For now I am just returning the interface from `App.GetNewsfeed()`, Changing

```
type App struct {
    newsFeed *NewsFeed
}

func (a *App) GetNewsFeed() *NewsFeed {
    return a.newsFeed
}
```

To

```
type App struct {
    newsFeed *NewsFeed
}

func (a *App) GetNewsFeed() INewsFeed {
    return a.newsFeed
}
```

Comment: The error describes the problem well.  The interface method is `GetNewsFeed() INewsFeed`.  The struct method is`GetNewsFeed() *NewsFeed`.   The methods have different signatures because `INewsFeed` and `*NewsFeed` are different types.

Comment: Ah I see. In my mental model I had it set-up that any time a struct was defined it was substitutable with an interface - but this is a method signature and not a parameter or assignment. Gotya - thanks